# Remove and detect Tinyscrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Tinyscrollbar](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) jquery plugin but there is two small problems I can't figure out on my own. Other than that everything works great.

First is there any way to detect if tinyscrollbar is added to an element? I'm adding tinyscrollbar dynamically and I need a way to detect if it's already added. If it's already added I guess it's better to use the update method.

My second question is if there is possible to remove tinyscrollbar from my element. I'm "closing" elements (the width is set very small) and I don't want my users to be able to scroll on that element any more. I can add the class disable to my tinyscrollbar element but that only hides the scrollbar. It's still possible to scroll with the mouse wheel.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if tinyscrollbar is loaded by checking if $( "#your-scrollbar-container-id" ).data('tsb') isnt empty.

Hmm there is no remove method. You probably could just unbind the scroll event.